# related to threads of services in android

Tags: android

the service is started by a single activity 4 times, how many threads are created by a service? And if service is started by 4 different activities then how many threads are created? Which function must be implemented inside a service inherited from intentService? how many threads are required to create inside this function?

```
public class HelloService extends Service {
  private Looper mServiceLooper;
  private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;

  // Handler that receives messages from the thread
  private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
      public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
          super(looper);
      }
      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
         long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5*1000;
          while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
              synchronized (this) {
                  try {
                      wait(endTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                  }
              }
          }
          // Stop the service using the startId, so that we don't stop
          // the service in the middle of handling another job
          stopSelf(msg.arg1);
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {

    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments",
            Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();

     mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
    mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
      msg.arg1 = startId;
      mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

      // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
      return START_STICKY;
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the service is started by a single activity 4 times, how many threads are created by a service?

Depends. Your `Service` creates a new thread in `onCreate`, so if it's never killed then you'll only have 1 thread created. If somehow it did get killed, you would end up with one for every time you started your `Service`.

> And if service is started by 4 different activities then how many threads are created?

Same as above.

> Which function must be implemented inside a service inherited from intentService?

You might try reading the [docs for `IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), you'd find you want to implement [`onHandleIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent%28android.content.Intent%29).

> how many threads are required to create inside this function?

Zero.

Comment: but don't you think that every service complete its life cycle at onDestroy(), so it gets killed at the end of service. So new thread creates every time??? and answer will be 4 in both cases???

Comment: Like I said, it depends. If you called it the 2nd (and/or 3rd/4th) time before your first call completed, then it wouldn't create a new Service/Thread. You should read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).